# Computing $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{-x^2} \cos(nx) dx $

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to find $$ \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{-x^2} \cos(nx) dx. $$

About the only thing I can think of is the well-known identity

$$ \sum_{n=-k}^k \cos(nx) = \sum_{n=-k}^k e^{inx} = \frac{\sin\left((k+\frac{1}{2})x\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}. $$

But this doesn't seem to simplify things much.

Comment: The answer is $2\pi$.

Comment: The integrand is even, so you can reduce it to a sum over the positive integers and an integral over $[0,\pi]$. That's all I could work out here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because $e^{-x^{2}}$ is an even function, the Fourier series for $e^{-x^{2}}$ is
$$
   e^{-x^{2}}\sim \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-t^2}dt+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-t^{2}}\cos(nt)dt\cos(nx).
$$
Evaluating at $x=0$ gives you what you want:
$$
\begin{align}
        1 & = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-t^{2}}dt+\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-t^{2}}\cos(nt)dt \\
          & = \frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-x^{2}}\cos(nt)dt
\end{align}
$$
Looks like the answer is $2\pi$.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there were two solid answers posted. So, let's try this using the complex Fourier series.

We have

$$e^{-x^2}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}C_ne^{inx}\tag 1$$

where

$$C_n=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-t^2}e^{-int}dt \tag 2$$

Using $(2)$ in $(1)$ with $x=1$ yields

$$1=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-t^2}e^{-int}dt \tag 3$$

whereupon multiplying both sides of $(3)$ by $2\pi$ and exploiting the fact that the sine function is odd reveals

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{2\pi=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-t^2}\cos (nt)\,dt }$$

Comment: This is how I ended up working the problem.

Comment: @PhilipHoskins I think this way is just a bit faster, don't you?  We don't have to worry about separating the constant term and unfolding a summation.  Clean and efficient!

Comment: Agreed. Also, it's the only way I really know how to compute a Fourier series

Comment: @PhilipHoskins Well it isn't the only way, but it is quite compact compared to the cosine-sine series.  No floating constant term with $\frac{a_0}{2}$, and a single $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ normalization.

Comment: Certainly, but it's the only way I bothered to commit to memory

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=e^{-x^2}$ is a function that belongs to the Schwarz space, and its Fourier series is uniformly converging to $f(x)$. So, if we set:
$$ c_k = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\cos(kx)\,dx $$
we have:
$$ e^{-x^2} = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\,dx + \sum_{n\geq 1} c_n \cos(nx) $$
and:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\cos(nx)\,dx = \pi\sum_{n\geq 1}c_n=\pi\, f(0)-\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\,dx $$
as well as:
$$ \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\cos(nx)\,dx=2\pi\, f(0)=\color{red}{2\pi}.$$

That also follows from the convergence in distribution of the [Dirichlet kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel) to the [Dirac delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) function.

Comment: I think its just a small bit faster using the complex FS.

Comment: Yes, in fact $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\cos (nx)\cos (nt)\sim 2\pi \delta(x-t)$ as a generalized function!  And this is true for any orthogonal basis in $\mathscr{L}^2$!!  Neat stuff.